# How do I get unique transactions from a table having duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose table transaction_record having following 10 records:

```
transaction_id,transaction_date,transaction_type,transaction_amount
123,03.11.2020,credit,20
123,04.11.2020,credit,20
123,03.11.2020,credit,30
123,04.11.2020,credit,30
123,03.11.2020,debit,20
123,04.11.2020,debit,20
123,03.11.2020,debit,30
123,04.11.2020,debit,30
456,03.11.2020,credit,100 #Should be shown in query
456,03.11.2020,debit,100  #Should be shown in query
```

Each transaction_id should appear twice in the table based on transaction_type values credit and debit. Due to an error transaction_id=123 have been erroneously posted for two dates: 03.11.2020 and 04.11.2020.
Transaction_id=456 is however correct.
How can I get only these two lines representing transaction_id=456 using SQL, given that I do not know which are the "good" transactions beforehand? I do know what the error happened on transaction_date='03.11.2020' and '04.11.2020'.
My dialect is sqlite, but I would appreciate answer in any SQL to understand the concept. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the preferred (expected) results for the given source data to support us to help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `transaction_id`s that you want if you `group by transaction_id` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select transaction_id 
from transaction_record
group by transaction_id
having count(*) = 2 and count(distinct transaction_date) = 1 and count(distinct transaction_type) = 2
```

Use the above query with the operator `IN` to select full rows from the table:

```
select * 
from transaction_record
where transaction_id in (
  select transaction_id 
  from transaction_record
  group by transaction_id
  having count(*) = 2 and count(distinct transaction_date) = 1 and count(distinct transaction_type) = 2
)
```

Or if you are sure that only correct `transaction_id`s have only 1 date then you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* 
from transaction_record t
where not exists (
  select 1 from transaction_record
  where transaction_id = t.transaction_id and transaction_date <> t.transaction_date
)
```

Or if you are sure that only correct `transaction_id`s have exacty 2 rows use `COUNT()` window function:

```
select transaction_id, transaction_date, transaction_type, transaction_amount
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by transaction_id) counter
  from transaction_record
)
where counter = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e1394990e4097f101ec2d4ca62464621).
Results:

```
> transaction_id | transaction_date | transaction_type | transaction_amount
> -------------: | :--------------- | :--------------- | -----------------:
>            456 | 03.11.2020       | credit           |                100
>            456 | 03.11.2020       | debit            |                100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I've applied your concept in my real table with some more data than in my illustration. The query is running and seems to take time, but this helps a lot!